# Кнопка "поделиться" Facebook. SDK JS FB.ui

Tags: facebook, facebook-api, facebooksdk

Не отображается картинка. Использую протокол `https`.

Использую код

```
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'og.shares',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object: {
                'og:url': this.dataset.url,
                'og:title': this.dataset.title,
                'og:description': this.dataset.description,
                'og:image': this.dataset.image
            }
        })
    },
    function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    });
```

Все отображается, а картинка нет. Она как бы загружается в размере 1px.

Comment: На локальной машине запускаете?

Comment: Нет, на рабочем сервере

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать метки `og:image:width` и `og:image:height`. В документации рекомендуют делать это при подобных проблемах

Comment: Написал так: ```FB.ui({
   method: 'share_open_graph',
   action_type: 'og.likes',
   action_properties: JSON.stringify({
    object: {
     'og:url': this.dataset.url,
     'og:title': this.dataset.title,
     'og:description': this.dataset.description,
     'og:image:url': this.dataset.image,
     'og:image:type': 'image/jpeg',
     'og:image:width': 1200,
     'og:image:height': 630
    }
   })
  },
  function (response) {
   console.log(response)
  });``` Не показывает

Comment: все значения должны быть в кавычках по стандарту Open Graph, отсюда могут быть проблемы. Так же гугление дало еще наводку на два варианта: ограничение прав доступа на сайте и протокол https, по которому не может адекватно вытянуть изображение

Comment: Еще можно попробовать другую запись. В стиле `<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/ogp.jpg" />` или в случае с https `<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/ogp.jpg" />`, значения подставляете свои

Comment: Кстати да. У меня защищенное соединение `https`

Comment: Тогда пробуйте с `og:image:secure_url`, как я вам расписал чуть выше

Comment: Сейчас буду пробовать, а через `FB.ui` не получится? Написать, например, `'og:image:secure_url': this.dataset.image`

Comment: Не пробовал, поэтому точно не смогу сказать, знаю что мой вариант работал, когда с таким сталкивался

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67941/discussion-between-valentin-dranyy-and--).